# Does an xsrf token isn’t required for http method other than POST and GET?

Tags: security, csrf, http-delete, http-put

Simple question but I couldn’t found the answer anywhere…

If I set actions for logged in users to be performed through http methods other than `get` or `post`, then javascript http requests respecting sop or cors is the only to perform those actions with credentials right ? (since it seems to not be possible with html)

Answer (score 0):

In general, it's not possible to perform XSRF attack on PUT/DELETE verbs because of HTML forms not supporting PUT/DELETE verbs and the browser blocking cross domain XmlHttpRequest. However, we should be aware of the fact that things might change in future, for example - PUT/DELETE verbs were included for HTML forms in early HTML5 drafts but were later removed.